# how does Switch work in Psipce?

Tags: pspice

I want to use this element to create a square wave(I know it's possible to make it using VPULSE):

[image]

But I don't know how **VON** and **VOFF** work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but I don't know how VON and VOFF work*

```
Your text says VON = 10 and VOFF = 0
```

The control signal on the left nodes has to be over 10 volts to activate the switch then, once activated, that control signal has to fall below 0 volts to deactivate the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When your voltage over 10 volts it works like a wire(short circuit) and when your voltage under 0 volt it works like open circuit. also you can change Von and Voff in pspice.